# How is direct sum of von Neumann algebras defined?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Consider the following fragment from Murphy's '$C^*$-algebras and operator theory'

[image]

How is $\bigoplus_\lambda A_\lambda$ defined? Is it $\{(a_\lambda)_\lambda\in \prod_\lambda A_\lambda: \sum_\lambda \Vert a_\lambda \Vert^2 < \infty\}$? Or $\{(a_\lambda)_\lambda\in \prod_\lambda A_\lambda: \sup_\lambda \Vert a_\lambda \Vert^2 < \infty\}$?

Comment: You can see the P30 of Murphy's book for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging through the book, it appears that Murphy intends to define the direct sum of von Neumann algebras to be
$$\oplus_\lambda A_\lambda=\{(a_\lambda):\sup_\lambda\|a_\lambda\|<\infty\}.$$
His definition of direct sum of Banach algebras can be found in Exercise 1.1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a bit confused though. We have $\bigoplus_\lambda A_\lambda \subseteq \prod_\lambda B(H_\lambda)$ and we want $\bigoplus_\lambda A_\lambda \subseteq B(\bigoplus_\lambda H_\lambda)$. How is that arranged?

Comment: I guess some identifications are going on.

Comment: @Aweygan What is this embedding?

Comment: @ε-δ Sorry, it's the other way around.  There is an embedding $\prod_\lambda B(H_\lambda)\subset B(\oplus_\lambda H_\lambda)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we have natural injective $*$-morphisms

$$\bigoplus_\lambda A_\lambda \hookrightarrow \bigoplus_\lambda B(H_\lambda) \hookrightarrow B\left(\bigoplus_\lambda H_\lambda\right)$$

and this allows us to see $\bigoplus_\lambda A_\lambda$ as a $*$-subalgebra of $B\left(\bigoplus_\lambda H_\lambda\right)$. The exercise is then to show that $\bigoplus_\lambda A_\lambda$ (or rather its image under the composition above) is strongly closed in $B\left(\bigoplus_\lambda H_\lambda\right)$.